# View on portion of tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a multiple dimensions tensor, let's take this simple one as example:

```
out = torch.Tensor(3, 4, 5)
```

I have to get a portion/subpart of this tensor `out[:,0,:]` and then apply the method `view(-1)`, but it's not possible:

```
 out[:,0,:].view(-1)
```

`RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Call .contiguous() before .view(). at ../aten/src/TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:203`

A solution is to clone the subpart:

```
 out[:,0,:].clone().view(-1)
```

Is there a better/faster solution than cloning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did will work fine. That said, a more portable approach would be to use [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape) which will return a view when possible, but will create a contiguous copy if necessary. That way it will do the fastest thing possible. In your case the data must be copied, but by always using `reshape` there are cases where a copy won't be produced.

So you could use

```
out[:,0,:].reshape(-1)
```

---

**Gotcha**

There's one important gotcha here. If you perform in-place operations on the output of `reshape` then that may or may not affect the original tensor, depending on whether or not a view or copy was returned.

For example, assuming `out` is already contiguous then in this case

```
>>> x = out[:,0,:].reshape(-1)    # returns a copy
>>> x[0] = 10
>>> print(out[0,0,0].item() == 10)
False
```

`x` is a copy so changes to it don't affect `out`. But in this case

```
>>> x = out[:,:,0].reshape(-1)     # returns a view
>>> x[0] = 10
>>> print(out[0,0,0].item() == 10)
True
```

`x` is a view, so in-place changes to `x` will change `out` as well.

---

**Alternatives**

A couple alternative are

```
out[:,0,:].flatten()    # .flatten is just a special case of .reshape
```

and

```
out[:,0,:].contiguous().view(-1)
```

Though if you want the fastest approach I **recommend against the latter method using `contiguous().view`** since, in general, it is more likely than `reshape` or `flatten` to return a copy. This is because `contiguous` will create a copy even if the underlying data has the same number of bytes between subsequent entries. Therefore, there's a difference between

```
out[:,:,0].contiguous().view(-1)       # creates a copy
```

and

```
out[:,:,0].flatten()                   # creates a non-contiguous view (b/c underlying data has uniform spacing of out.shape[2] values between entries)
```

where the `contiguous().view` approach forces a copy since `out[:,:,0]` is not contiguous, but `flatten`/`reshape` would create a view since the underlying data is uniformly spaced.

Sometimes `contiguous()` won't create a copy, for example compare

```
out[0,:,:].contiguous().view(-1)       # creates a view b/c out[0,:,:] already is contiguous
```

and

```
out[0,:,:].flatten()                   # creates a view
```

which both produce a view of the original data without copying since `out[0,:,:]` is already contiguous.

---

If you want to ensure that the `out` is decoupled completely from its flattened counterpart then the original approach using `.clone()` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough answer. This code is used just before calling multiple loss functions. In fact, I do this to isolate each output and then pass each one of them to the proper loss function. None of these function modify the tensor, so I should be ok.